# Is there a way to display animated SVG with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, svg, svg-animate

I am trying to display an animated SVG on Flutter,
this SVG itself contain animations, I don't want to animated from outside using an other library, if I try to apply SvgPicture.asset() to show it, it bring it without any animation.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter currently doesn't provide any SVG support directly.

You can use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_svg for basic SVG support

and [Lottie](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/lottie_flutter) or [Fluttie](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/fluttie) for animated vector graphics.